# Application that detects input activity and displays it on the screen

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, input

I'm having some issues with the touchpad / mouse, not sure which is it (maybe both).

Weird things happen without me doing anything. It's not a virus because I have an antivirus, and besides, I just re-installed my Windows...

Anyway is there an application out there that tells me when a mouse button has been pressed (and which one), moved, scrolled, or touchpad moved, key pressed, and whatever ? Basically any input activity. This way I can track where the problems come from...

Comment: "It's not a virus because I have an antivirus" - Famous last words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...]  is there an application out there that tells me when a mouse button has been pressed [...]

An easier way to troubleshoot your problem might be disabling your mouse and touchpad.

- First, disable both to see if the problem persists.

  **Neither antivirus software nor reinstallation rule out the possibility of a virus.**
- If the problem doesn't persist, disable them one by one to see which one is causing the problems.

If the cursor just moves randomly, it could be the mouse or the touchpad. However, if random **clicks** happen, form my personal experience, a faulty touchpad is far more likely.

Comment: One of the issues is automatic (non stop) horizontal scroll. If i disable the mouse it doesn't happen anymore. But another thing happens even if the mouse is disabled, I get the cursor moved in random places when I'm editing a text document. It's really annoying

Comment: If the mouse has an USB connector, try plugging it in different USB slots. If the horizontal scrolling happens in all slots, in all likelihood, your mouse is defective. I suppose the touchpad is built-in (notebook). Apparently random cursor movement can be caused by accidental contact with the touchpad while typing. It can also be a faulty touchpad. Did the both the touchpad and the mouse start to misbehave at the same time?